# set background of Navigation Drawer icon

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, menu

In my Navigation drawer my listview icon look like this [check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Lyt.png). So it's means that i have imposed the icon on the background.

I know through the Frame Layout, i can put the icon on a image but i'm confused how can i do it when it's declared in a `res/menu` folder

**menu.xml**

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
           <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_white_24dp"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_home" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/appointment_history"
            android:icon="@drawable/appointment_icon"
            android:title="@string/nav_history" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/contact_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/contact_us_icon"
            android:title="@string/nav_contact_us" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/setting_icon"
            android:title="@string/nav_setting" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

[new Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCShp.png)

Style.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#00BFF3</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#00BFF3</item>
</style>
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>


</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

v21

```
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to set the icon tint to null.

```
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Then you could create a xml drawable like this, in this example i will name it `rounded_corner_home`.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#007f12" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_home_white_24dp"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then you change the icon propriety of the menu item.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/rounded_corner_home"
    android:title="@string/nav_item_home" />
```

Here a screenshot of the result: [Screen](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2qRKz2K1PobbTVIenpvdW5QOW8)

Comment: I added more information and a screenshot of the result.

Comment: Sir your soloution is partially works... on kitkat it Works perfectly but on Lollipop it's shows the transparent background

Comment: Maybe you have and some resource with the same name in a folder with the suffix 'v21'

Comment: i copy the style color folder into the v21 folder and check Style.xml.......
but can't find anything

I added style sheet also in question

Comment: It's very strange because the screenshot i posted was taken in api 21.

Comment: ohhh so i think i m stuck in loop hole

Answer (score 0):

```
Using this code you can change the color of drawer icon : 

o NavigationView (it is located in activity_main.xml layout file) The default tint is black but you can use an even darker shade of black by using #000000

 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemIconTint="#000000"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: actually i m not talking about the icon tint, my concern is about the icon background check new image please

Comment: He is partially right, the tint will make all the icon have only one color and you want and icon with two color, but setting it to white will not help.

Comment: Ya exactly @henrique